# How to prove the Bonnesen's Inequality?

Tags: differential-geometry, inequality

The Bonnesen's Inequality states that for a convex plane curve, which has length $L$ and encloses an area $A$,

$$rL \ge A+ \pi r^2 \text{ for all } R_\text{in} \le r \le R_\text{out}$$

where $R_\text{in}$ is the inradius of the curve, and $R_\text{out}$ is the circumradius.

I've seen some papers show that it comes from $2A + 2Lr + 2 \pi r^2 \le 4rL$, but still I don't have any idea about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Google query with keywords "Bonnesen inequality proof", gave me at once 
this paper : (www.math.utah.edu/~treiberg/isoperim/Bonn.pdf)

Comment: I don't understand the definition of $e_{k}$ on page 4 in the paper, could you explain a bit about that? It's quite technical for me...

Comment: The # symbol means "number of elements" ; you take into acount the number of superpositions.  Precisely, $e_k$ is the set of those points that are in the dilated set and that are counted k times because of a folding (or even multiple foldings) of the dilated set. Most points are in $e_1$ ; in the example given here, the points that are in $e_2$ are those in the "entrant angle" which are counted twice in the "fan" that you find in the intersection of 2 rectangles. And in this example all the $e_k, k \geq 2$ are void.

Comment: Why are you interested in Bonnesen inequality ? Personally, I have had to use it some years ago for building specific shape parameters in image processing.

Comment: Recently, I am reading a paper about shrinking a curve into a point under the curve shortening flow. In this paper, Bonnesen inequality is used to prove that, for any convex curve, its isoperimetric ratio $L^{2}/A$ is decreasing under the flow.

Comment: Your description of $e_{k}$ is much better for me.